# With video sitemap are normal sitemaps still needed?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap, video-sitemap

For example:

- `video-post1.xml` - `video-post5.xml`
- `post-sitemap1.xml` - `post-sitemap5.xml`

have same post only different format. Should I remove the normal sitemaps or keep both? My site is streaming site.

Comment: You tagged this as SEO, but normal XML sitemaps have very little impact on SEO.  They don't help get pages indexed or ranked well.   At best they get all your pages crawled and give you extra stats in Google Search Console.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).  I believe that video sitemaps are required if you want your videos to get indexed in video search.

Comment: So I can conclude that it is safe to use video-sitemap.xml only?
because video-sitemap.xml already includes <loc> just like the regular sitemap.
if yes, I will disable my normal post sitemap, and use only video-sitemap.xml